# Why does subprocess.Popen not properly recognize command?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, cmd, subprocess, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to execute a "*.py" script (in a console from CMD by "python *.py"), which contains the following code ("convert" is a command of ImageMagick):

```
from subprocess import Popen
fp1 = 'convert'+' '+'Pictures\1110.6437v3.pdf[7]'+' '+'-thumbnail'+' '+'x156'+' '+'thumb.png'
print("fp1=", fp1)
pp = Popen(fp1)
```

I obtain the following output and error in the console window:

> fp1= convert Pictures\1110.6437v3.pdf[7] -thumbnail
> x156 thumb.png
>
> Invalid parameter - -thumbnail

It is strange because if I input the following command in CMD:

> convert 1110.6437v3.pdf[7] -thumbnail x156 thumb.png

it would be OK.

Comment: Thx for your suggestion on editing. For clarity, I have deleting "C:\Users\***\" in the question. But the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert on subprocess or Python. I have just dabbled a little with it. I think your fp1 syntax may be in error. Should it not be square brackets with commas (at least in Python 3.6). See https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

But the following works for me to run an ImageMagick command to create an image of the letter "P" in Python 3.6 on Mac OSX.

```
import subprocess

cmd = '/usr/local/bin/convert -size 30x40 xc:white -fill white -fill black -font Arial -pointsize 40 -gravity South -draw "text 0,0 \'P\'" /Users/fred/desktop/draw_text2.gif'

subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Using shell=True allows one not to have to parse each part of the command. For example with shell=False, I would have to do

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['/usr/local/bin/convert','-size','30x40','xc:white','-fill','white','-fill','black','-font','Arial','-pointsize','40','-gravity','South','-draw',"text 0,0 'P'",'/Users/fred/desktop/draw_text1.gif']

subprocess.call(cmd, shell=False)
```

Comment: Windows `CreateProcess` uses a command-line string instead of an `argv` array. An args list has to be converted back to a string via `subprocess.list2cmdline`. But there can be good reasons for using an args list on Windows. It helps write cross-platform code. Also, it uses the VC++ quoting rules that are common for Windows programs, which may be easier and more reliable than manually writing the command line.

Comment: When I add 'shell=True' in 'pp = Popen(fp1)' as 'pp = Popen(fp1, shell=True)', the error disappears, and I get the results that I want (although there are some warnings). Thx, @fmw42 and @ eryksun.